# jsp, drag and drop, mysql, treeview

Tags: mysql, ajax, jsp, drag-and-drop

i am using JSP. Now assume I have three tables in mysql related as follows

```
Department -> Project -> Members
```

So we can have many Departments each of which can have as many projects and each project will have members... Now i want to design my JSP page as follows

```
-DepartmentA
 -ProjectA
  >>Person1
  >>Person2
 -ProjectB
  >>Person12
  >>Person22
+DepartmentB
+DepartmentC
```

I want it visually appear as shown, as treeview. Also I want to be able to Rename/Add/Drop/Edit/... all of those tree components by right clicking if possible. Also additionally I want to be able to drag and drop, for example one member from one project to another, or one project from one department to another...

Can you please suggest any tools that I could possibly use? Preferably only open-source and free... Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a look at Ext.js. TreeView examples:

http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/#sample-6

Drag and Drop examples:

http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/#sample-9

Open source, and free with the right license.

Also jQuery has a very good plugin called jsTree. Check it out:

http://www.jstree.com/

More info on jQuery's tree control, with links to other tree plugins:

http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138128/Tree